# How do I make copies of a value from input?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-step-functions

I'm attempting to iterate over a small set of files using step functions. I call a lambda to fetch a list of files, which serves as input for my processing loop.

My input, going into the iteration part:

```
{
    "name": "ConfigureIterator",
    "input": {
        "files": {
            "count": 3,
            "filelist": [
                "foo",
                "bar",
                "fizz"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

My Pass state definition:

```
"ConfigureIterator": {
    "Type": "Pass",
    "Result": {
        "index": -1,
        "step": 1,
        "count": "$.files.count"
    },
    "ResultPath": "$.iterator",
    "Next": "Iterator"
}
```

I want to copy the value of `count` from input into the result of the pass step. However the substitution does not occur. The output:

```
  {
    "name": "ConfigureIterator",
    "output": {
        "files": {
        "count": 11,
        "filelist": [
            ...
        ]
        },
        "iterator": {
        "index": -1,
        "step": 1,
        "count": "$.files.count"
        }
    }
  }
```

Does a pass state not perform substitutions? Should I be using a task state instead? how do I define a "do-nothing" task state?

Answer (score 1):

Even in 2020, it appears the Result field in the Pass state does not interpolate values. However, the Parameters field does. The definition of the Pass state is that it passes its input to its output. So if you can get your *input* in the form you want, you'd automatically get the *output* you want. In other words, just replace "Result" with "Parameters" and you should be good. In other words:

```js
"ConfigureIterator": {
    "Type": "Pass",
    "Parameters": {
        "index": -1,
        "step": 1,
        "count.$": "$.files.count"
    },
    "ResultPath": "$.iterator",
    "Next": "Iterator"
}
```

Comment: You forgot the trailing '. $' it should be: 
 "count.$": "$.files.count"